# How to use Play2 HTTP client's methods that take Iteratees?

Tags: http, scala, stream, playframework-2.0

I intend to use Iteratees with Play2 [HTTP client's methods](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.x/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS%24%24WSRequestHolder.html) that take them. Play2's [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2-SNAPSHOT/Iteratees) are quite complicated.

Taken these Play2 methods (this [GET method](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala#L366)):

```scala
 /**
 * performs a GET with supplied body
 * @param consumer that's handling the response
 */
 def get[A](consumer: ResponseHeaders => Iteratee[Array[Byte], A]):
   Future[Iteratee[Array[Byte], A]] =
     prepare("GET").executeStream(consumer)
```

and this [PUT method](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala#L401):

```scala
 /**
 * performs a PUT with supplied body
 * @param consumer that's handling the response
 */
 def putAndRetrieveStream[A, T](body: T)
   (consumer: ResponseHeaders => Iteratee[Array[Byte], A])
     (implicit wrt: Writeable[T], ct: ContentTypeOf[T]):
       Future[Iteratee[Array[Byte], A]] =
         prepare("PUT", body).executeStream(consumer)
```

how do I call this `get` method so I get response's body as `Array[Byte]`? And how do I call the `putAndRetrieveStream` method so that it sends a given `Array[Byte]` in the request's body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your result as `Array[Byte]` so you need to create an `Iteratee[Array[Byte],Array[Byte]]`:

```
val resp  = req.get((r:ResponseHeaders => Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]()))
resp onComplete {
    case Success(iter) => iter match {
        case Done(bytes,rem) => do_something_with_bytearray(bytes)       
    }
    case Failure(t) => do_something(t)
}
```

Similarly:

```
val resp = req.putAndRetrieveStream(data)((r:ResponseHeaders => Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]()))
```

where data is the data you want to send with the put request. It can be string or byte array etc.

NOTE: I haven't tried this code but this will give you the right direction.